# Losing access to the keys stored on iOS Key Chain

Tags: ios, key, chain

We have an app on the iPhone App Store which needs to store the user id and password on the device for features like Touch ID and Remember Me.

Both user id and password are encrypted and the respective AES key is stored in the device key chain.

Now, the problem statement is : we are unable to retrieve the AES key from key chain every time we update the app from AppStore and also when user updates iOS on their device (eg : from iOS 9.1 to 9.2).

Since we are unable to retrieve the key, we are unable to decrypt the user id and password that results in failing a couple of key features every time user updates the app (eg : Remember Me and Touch ID).

This is becoming a huge concern since the issue continues until user totally uninstalls and reinstalls the app.. When user reinstalls the app, every thing works fine. We can enable Remember Me, Touch ID features and they are enabled fine and works fine.

What must be going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

In general keys in the keychain persist across update and even deletion and re-installs. So, there is something you are doing that is not correct. Please provide more information.

It is not necessary to encrypt the name and password, they can be stored directly in the keychain, the keychain encrypts it's contents.

Are you changing the Bundle ID when you update? If so have you made the keychain available to a group all the updates belong to?